# Ignore the function call for a specific time

Tags: javascript

I am looking for an optimal solution for the described problem.

Scenario: There is a function **getData()** which is being called every second.
If it is called now I want to ignore any call to this function for let say 5 sec.

how best we can achieve this in javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: You can check against a timestamp; there will be better alternatives though, depending on your code

Comment: @baao but how to "protect" the function from being executed anywhere else?

Comment: @ritaj setTime won't solve the issue, I want to execute in asap if no call is being made and then ignore any call to same function for a specific time.

Comment: @messerbill see justina's answer

Comment: do you use webworkers in your program ?

Comment: @codeanjero, no i don't use web worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a flag and toggle it after 5 seconds and on each not ignored call:

```
var shouldIgnore = false;

function getData() {
    if (shouldIgnore) {
        return;
    }
    shouldIgnore = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        shouldIgnore = false;
    }, 5000);

    /* rest of code */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Save last call time and check if passed more than 5 seconds:

```
var lastCall = 0;

function getData() {
    if (lastCall >= moment().subtract(5, 'mins').unix()) {
        return;
    }

    lastCall = moment().unix();

    /* rest of code */
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a library for that? Just do a setTimeout...

Comment: @ritaj setTimeout is not the right thing to use, `new Date()` would suffice though

Comment: @baao Is it not? Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @ritaj `setTimeout` makes your function async. That may lead to issues when returning some content.

Comment: @baao Yes, it's possible to use `new Date()`, but used momentjs as example

Comment: @justinas it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There are may may using setTimeout you can do. I have give sample example with some util mathod to make it simpler.

**Throttle Function:**

```
const throttle = (fn, ms = 0) => {
  let lastRunTime;
  return function(...args) {
    const currTime = +new Date();
    if (!lastRunTime || currTime - lastRunTime > ms) {
      lastRunTime = +new Date();
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }
  };
};
```

**How to use it:**

```
(async function throttleEx() {
  const logTill1Sec = throttle(log, 1 * 1000);
  logTill1Sec("deepakt_1");
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500)); //2 sec virtual delay
  logTill1Sec("deepak_t2");
})();
```

**Output:**
`Mr. deepakt_1`

> **Here you notice, even I call logAfter5Sec multiple times. It execute last one. You can write same way call once.**

```js
const throttle = (fn, ms = 0) => {
  let lastRunTime;
  return function(...args) {
    const currTime = +new Date();
    if (!lastRunTime || currTime - lastRunTime > ms) {
      lastRunTime = +new Date();
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }
  };
};
(async function throttleEx() {
  const logTill1Sec = throttle(log, 1 * 1000);
  logTill1Sec("deepakt_1");
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500)); //2 sec virtual delay
  logTill1Sec("deepak_t2");
})();

const debounce = (fn, ms = 0) => {
  let timeoutId;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), ms);
  };
};

const dLog = debounce(log, 200); //ms time

dLog("deepak11");
dLog("deepak22");
dLog("deepak33");

function log(name) {
  console.log(`Mr. ${name}`);
}

(async function() {
  const logAfter5Sec = debounce(log, 1 * 1000);
  logAfter5Sec("deepak");
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500)); //2 sec virtual delay
  logAfter5Sec("deepak2");
})();
```

Comment: Clean up more, added debounce funtion